# Loading Template based on click

Tags: php, joomla

hi  i am a novice at coding so need any help possible.  i am using joomla and a component built for  joomla. I want to make a template load in place of existing template when a link is clicked. That link would load  the below statement. over existing page.

```
   <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('common1'); ?>
```

Comment: i am trying to research and learn. my guess i would need a variable  like if the link is clicked it would then load the common1 template. if not it would load the default.  To bad i dont have no clue lol

Comment: Is this a custom situation with a limited set of such link/load combinations? In that case I would just make menu links and assign templates to them as desired.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to switch templates via a url would be to simply include the template name in a url parameter as shown below:

```
http://website.com/index.php?template=myTemplateName
```

Where **myTemplateName** is one of the templates installed on your joomla site.

Comment: but not calling the  theme of the site  the template for the component

Comment: My bad. 
I mistook the type of "template" you were trying to load. I suspect what you need to do has to be wrapped within the view file that you're currently displaying for the loadTemplate() method to work.

Comment: thats where i am stuck in the template i can add a link and  then just call  &mytemplate=common1 but writing the variable i have no clue how to do that